# If $X$ has the Fatou property, then $L$ has the Fatou property

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

I am trying to prove (or disprove) the following:

**If $X$ has the $\sigma$-Fatou property, then $L^1(\mu,X)$ has the $\sigma$-Fatou's property.**

Here, $L^1(\mu,X)=\{f:\Omega\to X \,|\, f \text{ is Bochner integrable}\}$, $X$ is a Banach space.

**Definition.** Let $X$ a Banach lattice. We say that $X$ has the $\sigma$-Fatou property if for every increasing sequence $(x_n)\subset X^+$, with $\sup\|x_n\|<\infty$, then $\sup x_n\in X$.

**Theorem.** $f:\Omega\to X$ is Bochner integrable if and only if $\|f\|_1=\int_\Omega \|f(t)\|_X<\infty$.

This is my try:
Suppose $X$ has the $\sigma$-Fatou property. Let $(f_n)\subset L^1(\mu,X)^+$ an increasing sequence of functions such that $\sup \|f_n\|<\infty$ (We want to prove that $\sup f_n\in L^1(\mu,X)$, i.e. $\sup f_n$ is Bochner integrable). Since $(f_n)\subset L^1(\mu,X)$ is a increasing sequence of functions and $\sup\|f_n\|<\infty$, then $(f_n(t))\subset X^+$ and $\sup\|f_n(t)\|<\infty$ for every $t\in \Omega$. Otherwise, $$\|\sup f_n\|_1=\int_\Omega\|\sup f_n(t)\|_X\leq \int_\Omega \sup\|f_n(t)\|_X<\infty$$
Then $L^1(\mu,X)$ has Fatou property.

My question is: the inequality that I used in the previous compute, is it correct?, i.e. $\|\sup f_n(t)\|\leq \sup\|f_n(t)\|$?

If there is something wrong with my proof, thank you let me know.

Comment: What is $X^{+}$ and what is $sup_nx_n$?

Comment: $X$ is a Banach space with a partial order $\leq$, $X^+=\{x\in X:0\leq x\}$ and $\sup x_n=\sup\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: But you started with 'Let $X$ be Banach space'.

Comment: you right, sorry, $X$ is a Banach space with a partial order..